# C# serial port does not exist

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I have an Arduino that send information on the serial port (in this case on `COM3`).

The code is:

```
class Program
{
    private SerialPort mySerialPort;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine("PORTS: " + String.Join(" ", p.getSerialPortsList())+ ", enter to start.");
        Console.Read();    
        p.SerialRead("COM3");
    }

    public String[] getSerialPortsList()
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        return ports;
    }

    public void SerialRead(String com)
    {
        mySerialPort = new SerialPort(com, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        mySerialPort.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data:");
        Console.WriteLine(mySerialPort.ReadExisting());
        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

The first console output is

> PORTS: COM10 COM9 COM3 enter to start.

Anyway the compiler lunch the exception `System.IO.IOException` where it says that `COM3` does not exist.
I try also different ports, anyway the exception is always the same.

Anyway, if I try to read the COM10, everything work (a set of empty data).
I am using Window 10 x64.
Thanks!

Comment: You may want to add an "arduino" tag to garner attention from those more experienced with Arduino programming.

Comment: Note that [`GetPortNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx) says: "The port names are obtained from the system registry (for example, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM). If the registry contains stale or otherwise incorrect data then the GetPortNames method will return incorrect data.". Does Device Manager show COM3 under the ports section?

Comment: Yes, in Device Manager there is the Arduino device with assigned the COM3 port.

Comment: I reboot window and I can read the ports.  This is the window magic.

Answer (score 0):

I reboot window and everything works well. Now I can read each port. 
I do not why its work; anyway, it works!